# HTML entity numbers in xslt

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm attempting to transform HTML to XML. My Input HTML is obtained dynamically, and the input HTML has html entity numbers as below.

HTML Input:

```
    <root>
      <h1>Hello stack Over flow</h1>
      <H1 align="left">The list will be managed with a &#160;<SUB>of &#169;&#160;&#174;</H1>
      </root>
```

My transform looks as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy >
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output from the transform is writing all html entity numbers as html special characters.

The desired output should have html entity numbers instead of html characters. Please help me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to put `encoding="US-ASCII"` on your `xsl:output` directive, that way any characters outside of that encoding should be output as character references.

Comment: I have done that..however it is giving ascii format Like below. but i need html number format.

  <h1>Hello stack Over flow</h1>

  <H1 dir="ltr" align="left">
    The list will be managed with a &#xA0;<SUB>
      of &#xA9;&#xA0;&#xAE;&#xA0;<SUP>
        <SMALL>TM</SMALL>
      </SUP>&#xA0;&#x20AC;&#xA0;&#xA9;
    </SUB>
  </H1>

Comment: Find out which XSLT processor you use and check whether it has any option to output decimal character references instead of hexadecimal ones. But you are outputting XML where both formats are allowed I think, even Html supports both notations I think so I am not sure why you insist on decimal character references.